# Oracle Apex: show picture in report from a different table?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following apex report :

---

```
select id,
    user_ as participant,
    --This is a blob
    dbms_lob.getlength(MY_UTILITIES.GetUserPicture(user_)) as Picture,  
    order_ as order_
from My_Operations
```

---

I would like to display the column Picture as an image in the report. It's a blob stored in another table : Table My_Users (the Primary key column name is 'ID')

I configured as follows the Picture Column :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGO6o.png)

The report generates but the picture doesn't show :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQa4Q.png)

I'm sure using this implementation Apex has no way to know that the field picture corresponds to the row X in the table My_Users.

Does anyone know how to correct that please ?

Cheers,

Comment: This won't work.  What is the structure of your two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way APEX displays images in reports is somewhat weird and wacky it would seem.  What you need to do is apparently undocumented but I believe it is as follows:

1. The column that will be displayed as an image must contain the length of the BLOB column (which you have done correctly). I found this out from [this blog post](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2016/09/01/how-to-display-a-blob-image-in-an-apex-report).
2. The column specified for Primary Key Column 1 specified in the BLOB attributes of that column must also appear in the report **with the same name**. I figured that out by trial and error.

You have aliased column `user_` as `participant`.  APEX requires it to be called `ID` - but you already have a different column called ID!  So I think you should try this:

```
select id as op_id,
    user_ as id,
    dbms_lob.getlength(MY_UTILITIES.GetUserPicture(user_)) as Picture,  
    order_ as order_
from My_Operations
```

Comment: Note that there is another option if you want full control over it. Create an application process which downloads the BLOB from the table to the end-user. Now, use `apex_util.prepare_url` wrapped inside an <img>-Tag to provide a link. I can provide a full example if you are interested.